# Data from Json api to wordpress post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, json-api

i want to add posts on wordpress based on data that i have on api

the api have images links for every Categories

this is what api returns

```
   {
  "images": [
    [
      13, 
      "8d/8dc9d0932799a08908f1a1403c8174752ae8f945fff35a17e91a779b.png", 
      1781, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      12, 
      "b7/b7c396aa354bb314b8a309e0c26101f674e06aa0e873a5f0add3200b.png", 
      901, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      11, 
      "5a/5a15d7c7526bee984322b960d8079989f8c315d7f46fa0d5c82a73b0.png", 
      901, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      10, 
      "31/31ac672cb746f1565a5b2eecc98dbf3d59482bf741c1ddf6a4d9a1ab.png", 
      1765, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      9, 
      "3b/3b83beebab7b2b7bf5e876bb75e62fe38c311a527605c9b2b05a11a5.png", 
      903, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      8, 
      "84/848b054544b04459587081582f0a4c90dbb667893583756d43e837f8.png", 
      898, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      7, 
      "0e/0ed1491ad3aa961d71365e1288daec7753c6a1041e1cda6eb4032113.png", 
      897, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      6, 
      "ac/acec8290a3b6bfe8b5ba9ca699ad56bbc1a1521372f8b7e0f05c11c7.png", 
      895, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      5, 
      "56/56bfdbc6a75d1ad289f94157603e344def10b6f9dc635809e44f1b71.png", 
      894, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      4, 
      "7b/7b5eb8a756108c98f9342bcf9e6646d2d5e4fe15080d0354f0d99b12.png", 
      896, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      3, 
      "85/857be425c2215b442537d0a1626139adf3f9478aa0ca536029741b5f.png", 
      894, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      2, 
      "90/90b7e6c0bca3fb638820900d28a74d7a783b5e70d72ebfbbe44fd1a5.png", 
      895, 
      1300
    ], 
    [
      1, 
      "50/5008a681f7e97237ac495b4406b61d6738ea041521cd8f0c10787d6c.jpg", 
      800, 
      800
    ], 
    [
      0, 
      "ea/ea150e69da918dd501c961c4f88ec41f9c3de90ee96b909590f9cdcd.png", 
      898, 
      1300
    ]
  ]
}
```

and this is for just one category and i want to put post for every category that contains this images using html

but what the best method to add this post i thought to create new app outside wordpress and give it access to database and insert them from there but it's not secured i know

there is any other way to do that

Answer (score 0):

You can use the wordpress functions in every php script outside your wordpress installation or unrelated to your wordpress. Just include these files:

```
 define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
 require('/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-blog-header.php');
 require('/path/to/your/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/admin.php');
```

Then you can loop through the data and execute the wp_insert_post() function from WordPress.

```
$new_post = array(
    'post_title' => $leadTitle,
    'post_content' => $leadContent,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_date' => $timeStamp,
    'post_author' => $userID,
    'post_type' => $postType,
    'post_category' => array($categoryID)
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
```

(example out of my scripts, you need to assign the variables matching your needs)

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/

This is safer than a direct DB insert, you don`t have to mess with the database and the inserted data is sanitized by WordPress.

Regards Tom